# Time complexity of two separate nested for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

An introductory [textbook](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=f57uDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA225&ots=GHH9GQ402A&dq=%22potentially%20involves%20looking%20at%20each%20element%22&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q=%22potentially%20involves%20looking%20at%20each%20element%22&f=false) presents the following function as an example of polynomial complexity:

```py
def intersect(L1, L2):
    """
    Assumes L1 and L2 are lists
    Returns a list without duplicates that is intersection of L1 and L2
    """
    
    # Part i - Build a list containing common elements
    tmp = []
    for e1 in L1:
        for e2 in L2:
            if e1 == e2:
                tmp.append(e1)
                break
             
    # Part ii - Build a list without duplicates
    result = []
    for e in tmp:
        if e not in result:
            result.append(e)
    
    return result
```

**Questions**

1. The author says that the running time for part (i) is order `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))`, but this seems to imply that part (i) runs in `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))` in *all* cases, is this correct?

When I tried working through the example, I get different running times for the worst- and best-cases:

- **Worst-case:** All of L1's elements match with the last element of L2 ==> `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))`.
- **Best-case:** All of L1's elements match with the first element of L2 ==> `Θ(len(L1))`.

...so I would have said part (i) is order `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))` in the *worst-case*.

2. The author then says that part (ii) is not `Θ(len(tmp))` but rather `Θ(len(tmp)*len(result))` since `e not in result` may require us to examine all elements in `result` and this would run in `Θ(len(result))`. But since `len(result)` and `len(tmp)` are bounded by the smaller of `len(L1)` and `len(L2)`, `Θ(len(tmp)*len(result))` can be ignored.

I understand that `Θ(len(tmp)*len(result))` is an additive term and can therefore be ignored, but again I'm not sure why the author makes a blanket statement regarding part (ii) - are they saying part (ii) is `Θ(len(tmp)*len(result))` in *all* cases?

Since the loop in part (ii) depends on the output of the loop in part (i), I figured `result` would be length 1 in the worst-case (as I've defined it above) and therefore part (ii)'s worst-case running time would be order `Θ(len(tmp))`, not `Θ(len(tmp)*len(result))`. This seems wrong, but I'm not sure how to characterise such loops.

I'm new to this topic so any guidance would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT: The same passage in an [older edition](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=KabKDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA145&ots=EUBTJ_QY9p&dq=%22Implementation%20of%20list%20intersection%22&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q=%22Implementation%20of%20list%20intersection%22&f=false) of the book uses Big-O in place of Big-Theta.

Comment: "since len(result) and len(tmp) are bounded by the smaller of len(L1) and len(L2)..." is a wrong argument. You could have L1=L2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The author says that the running time for part (i) is order `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))`, but this seems to imply that part (i) runs in `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))` in all cases, is this correct?

No. The author uses Big Θ in the sense that they explain in section 11.2 of that same chapter, in the *third* edition (text differs from second edition) -- note the use of "worst case" which I highlighted:

> Many computer scientists will abuse Big O notation by making statements like, "the complexity of f(x) is O(x²)." By this they mean that in the **worst case** f will take no more than O(x²) steps to run. [...]
>
> [...] we will use **Big Theta** (Θ) when we are describing something that is both an upper and a **lower bound** on the asymptotic **worst-case** running time.

Then your following thought is also explained:

> ...so I would have said part (i) is order `Θ(len(L1)*len(L2))` in the *worst-case*.

You'll now understand that this is exactly what the author wants to say.

> Since the loop in part (ii) depends on the output of the loop in part (i), I figured `result` would be length 1 in the worst-case (as I've defined it above) and therefore part (ii)'s worst-case running time would be order `Θ(len(tmp))`, not `Θ(len(tmp)*len(result))`.

It is true that you defined **a** worst case earlier on, but there are other instances of worst case behaviour for part (i), that also perform worst in part (ii).

Take for instance the case where `L1` has  unique elements, and where `L2` is a copy of `L1`.

In part (i), the inner loop will then iterate once the first time, it will iterate twice the second time,... etc. So in total the inner loop makes 1+2+3+4+...+ iterations. This [corresponds to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) (+1)/2 iterations, which is Θ(²), a worst case. `tmp` will be a copy of `L1`.

Now look at part (ii): the `if` block will be executed in each iteration since `tmp` has no duplicates. The `in` operation will scan all values in `result`. In the first iteration, `result` will be empty, so there is nothing to scan, but in the second it will have 1 element, then 2, so again we get 0+1+2+3...+(-1) steps inside the `in` operator which is Θ(²).

Comment: Thanks @trincot, using Big-O makes sense but I just discovered that the newer version of the book (and the one I've been referencing) actually uses Big-Theta (see [here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=f57uDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA226&ots=GHH9GQ3Z4D&dq=%22implementation%20of%20list%20intersection%22&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q=%22implementation%20of%20list%20intersection%22&f=false)). This is the most recent edition, whereas the one linked to in my post is from 2016.

Comment: Also, this quote from the 2016 ed doesn't make sense to me: "When we say that f(x) is O(x²) we are implying that x² is both an upper and a lower bound on the asymptotic worst-case running time" - isn't it Big-Theta that provides the asymptotic upper and lower bounds on a function?

Comment: Yes, and I see that in that newer version they also added the following phrase to what I quoted: "To avoid this kind of confusion, we will use **Big Theta**..." I will update my answer to align it with the newer edition.

Comment: Answer updated to reference the third edition of the book.

Comment: Thank you @trincot, would you also substitute "Θ" for "O" in the last two paragraphs of your answer?

Comment: Sure, it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. If L1 only contains the first element of L2 repeated, the first loops will run L1 times and tmp take length L1. Then the length of result will not exceed 1 and the last loops take time L1 as well.

But this does not contradict the book.